# Create ConfigurableProduct programmatically, using Repository pattern

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

This is as far as it gets me trying to create product:

```
public function __construct(ProductInterfaceFactory $factory,
                            ProductRepositoryInterface $repository)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
    $this->factory = $factory;
}

public function setEntity($source)
{
    $product = $this->factory->create();
    $product->setSku($source->getId());
    $product->setName($source->getDescription());
    $product->setPrice($source->getUnitPrice());
    $product->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $this->repository->save($product);
}
```

Now, how do I create a configurable product and link it to this product? There is no ConfigurableProductRepository, so how do I achieve this?

For the record: I see lots of Google results do something like [this](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-create-a-configurable-magento-2-product.html), but it feels like less elegant than the Factory/Repository pattern to do CRUD. Mainly because I need to work directly against a concrete class rather than against an interface...

Is there no other way to create ConfigurableProduct?

I'm using version 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

```
$configurable_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$configurable_product->setSku('test-configurable');
$configurable_product->setName('test name configurable');
$configurable_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$configurable_product->setStatus(1);
$configurable_product->setTypeId('configurable');
$configurable_product->setPrice(11);
$configurable_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$configurable_product->setCategoryIds(array(31));
$configurable_product->setStockData(array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
    )
);

$configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(152),$configurable_product); //attribute ID of attribute 'size_general' in my store
$configurableAttributesData = $configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurable_product);

$configurable_product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$configurable_product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

$configurableProductsData = array();
$configurableProductsData[$simple_product_id] = array( //[$simple_product_id] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
    '0' => array(
        'label' => 'S', //attribute label
        'attribute_id' => '152', //attribute ID of attribute 'size_general' in my store
        'value_index' => '193', //value of 'S' index of the attribute 'size_general'
        'is_percent'    => 0,
        'pricing_value' => '10',
    )
);
$configurable_product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);

$configurable_product->save();
```

try it once

Comment: I'm sorry, have you tested it to be working on version 2.2.3? The function setUsedProductAttributeIds, setUsedProductAttributeIds are not in Product anymore. setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes, setConfigurableAttributesData, setConfigurableProductsData are all not there anymore.

Comment: Also: Product doesn't have save() function anymore? (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php), probably to encourage people to use Repository rather than working against the Product class directly.